# How to refer to a sheet by name in function for last row?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a function to find the last row.

```vb
Sub test()
    Msgbox LROW(1,1)
End Sub
    
Function LROW(shtNumber as Integer, Col As Integer) as string
    Dim shtName as string
    ShtName="Sheet" & shtNumber
    LROW=ShtName . Cells(rows.count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

I receive error

> invalid qualifier

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `.`?   It will be `sheets(shtname).` too

Comment: see: [Refer to Sheets by Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/refer-to-sheets-by-name)

Comment: Thanks Nathan, My sheets have names, cant change their names to sheet 1 , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShtName` is a String (that holds the name of a sheet), *not* a sheet.

Use something like

```
Dim shtName as string
ShtName="Sheet" & shtNumber
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(ShtName)  ' Consider to use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtName)
LROW = ws.Cells(rows.count, col).End(xlUp).Row
```